# How to differentiate between two usages of a word that have different meanings in different contexts

Tags: grammaticality

Suppose that I am a mobile application developer and have defined a feature in my app called 'events' that are representatives of real life events (birthday parties, marathons, etc.).

How would I, **in the same sentence**, use the word 'event' to mean the application's feature and another word 'event' to refer to the meaning of this word as it appears in the Oxford dictionary, without using capitalization, quotation marks, italics or any other formatting?

Sample sentence: "Events [the one in the app] are indicative of various events [the English one]."

Comment: Are the events in the app not English ones? Do you mean to distinguish between a *real life event* and a *metaphorical event*?

Comment: The events in the app are english ones. I want to differentiate between the notion of the event feature and a _reallife_ event (and it would be nice if there were a way to do that without saying 'event feature'

Comment: Would it be an option to explain once that you have *representations* or *metaphors* for real life events in your app, and from that on refer to *actual events* and *representations*?

Comment: With proper wording, this will be understood from context. You could clarify (parenthetically) which is meant in each case - similar to your sample sentence.

Comment: You're going to need some adjectives. Might I suggest "software events" and "calendar events". Or "calendar entries".

Comment: @RaimundKrämer That's what I finally went with. Thanks!

Comment: @Davo thanks for the suggestion. I forgot to mention that the document was slightly formal and I wanted to avoid parenthesis. However that's definitely one way I could do it in the future

Comment: @Pam  I had to use the exact term 'events' since it referred to software code named 'events' and so although throughout the document I could use an adjective-prefixed term, at the start I had to use just 'events'. Thanks!